# Scroll a CSS background when user scrolls the webpage - parallax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I've got a page I built - it has a small section where I include links to my social sites.

That section currently has a nice background out of CSS - but what I would like is for that background to 'scroll', while the user scrolls up or down the sites page.

This is a parallax effect - but I'm not sure if this can even be done with a CSS background.

I've tried a few tutorials here or there online without any success.

I created a [codepen on the basics of what I have](http://codepen.io/hannylicious/pen/GJrEqb)

But here is my HTML:

```
<div id="social-row">
  <div id="para-social-bg">
    <div class="social-icons" id="para-social-shadow">
      <h4>SOCIAL STUFF</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="mytwitter" title="http://www.mytwitter.com" class="icon-social twitter">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.myfacebook.com" title="me on Facebook" class="icon-social facebook">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.myblog.com" title="my news" class="icon-social atom">Blog feed</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.myinstagram.com" title="me on Instagram" class="icon-social instagram">Instagram</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...and my CSS:

```
#para-social-bg {
background-color: #6d695c;
background-image:
repeating-linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(255,255,255,.1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px),
repeating-linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1), rgba(255,255,255,.1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px),
linear-gradient(60deg, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1)),
linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.1));
background-size: 70px 120px;  
}

#para-social-shadow {
box-shadow:         inset 0 6px 10px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.8),
                    inset 0 -6px 10px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 6px 10px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.8),
                    inset 0 -6px 10px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 6px 10px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.8),
                    inset 0 -6px 10px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  }
```

Ultimately I just need the argyle styling to 'scroll' vertically as the user scrolls down the page (but at a slower speed than the user is scrolling the page - so it appears to be 'behind' the other sections above and below it).

Any thoughts?  Open to all ideas - CSS, JS, JQUERY - whatever.

CSS would be optimal, JS can be done without worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $("#para-social-bg").css({"background-position":"left " +($(window).scrollTop()*.5) + "px"})
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdRjXJ

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
body { 
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I'm not sure if it will move at a slower speed or not. But this allows your background to scroll the scroll of the browser.

Comment: This does not create a 'true' parallax effect. Although it does keep the image in position as the other content scrolls, I think the OP is looking for a solution that makes it scroll slower than the other content.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll take a gander for that. I've never heard of that though, unless you had a .gif that made it seem like it was moving slower.

Comment: This is correct - also - I'm not using an image as a background.  My background is created via CSS.  It appears to make a difference.

Comment: Are you using a linear gradient to create your background? @Hanny

Comment: Yes - as per the CSS above.

Answer (score 0):

I use [StellarJS](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/), it is a relatively lightweight and feature-rich JQuery plugin for adding parallax effects to backgrounds and even divs and other elements. It is as easy as adding a `data` attribute to your HTML tag and then running the Stellar object on the window. It does require JQuery to be included with your website, but it is likely you are using JQuery already. For more information and demos, check it out [here](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/)

Answer (score 0):

Along with what everyone else has said, here is a tutorial that uses javascript html and css to get the parallax effect when scrolling

http://www.kirupa.com/html5/smooth_parallax_scrolling.htm

Comment: It would appear that tutorial uses an image as a background.  I'm using CSS as my background - that's where I'm getting hung up I believe.

Comment: It may be better for you to use an image rather than CSS.

Comment: drats.  Trying to cut down on loading images and such.   Back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on pure css parallax http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your background (`#bg`) is a `fixed` element with `top: 0;` on load and a lower `z-index` than the rest of elements. You get the `scrolTop` and then give the background a negative `top`, but with a smaller number:

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrl = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#bg').css('top', -scrl/20);
});
```

I just put 20, if it's too fast you can increase it and vice versa.

**CSS:**

```
#bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("BACKGROUND_URL");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 2000px;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/jddf929q/1/)